# How would I translate the following assembly code from the compiler to C when working with structs?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, struct, x86-64

Suppose I define a new `struct`:

```
struct s {
   int *x;
   struct {
      short sh[2];
      int i;
   } w;
   struct s *next;
};
```

In addition, I write a function to initialize it:

```
void init_s(struct s *ss) {
   ss->w.sh[1] = /* Line 1 */;
   ss->x = /* Line 2 */;
   ss->next = /* Line 3 */;
}
```

The compiler generates the following assembly code for `init_s`:

```
init_s:             # line 1
   movw 8(%rdi), %ax    # line 2
   movw %ax, 10(%rdi)   # line 3
   leaq 12(%rdi), %rax  # line 4
   movq %rax, (%rdi)    # line 5
   movq %rdi, 16(%rdi)  # line 6
   retq                 # line 7
```

What I am trying to do is fill in the missing lines of code for `init_s` based on the assembly. I have figured out (or at least I think so) lines 1 and 2. Line 1 should be `ss->w.sh[0]` and line 2 should be `&(ss->w.sh[2])`. However, I am having trouble with line 3. I think it would be `&(ss->x)` based on the assembly, but I feel like this is incorrect and I'm not sure why. Any feedback or suggestion would be greatly appreciated in helping me learn more about assembly and structs.

Comment: While I understand your `init_s` is an example with placeholders, maybe you should also show the actual compiling code you use to generate the assembly?

Comment: @AKX: I think the idea is to reverse-engineer `init_s`.

Comment: Right you are. I didn't realize the first part was hypothetical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Line 1 should be `ss->w.sh[0]`

I agree.

> line 2 should be `&(ss->w.sh[2])`

That's the right address, except that `ss->w.sh` only has 2 elements so `w.sh[2]` is out of bounds.  This is instead a pointer to the next member of the struct, i.e. `ss->x = &(ss->w.i)`.  That also makes sense with the `ss->x` member being `int *` instead of `short *`.

> However, I am having trouble with line 3. I think it would be `&(ss->x)` based on the assembly

Similar issue: it's true that `%rdi` could be a pointer to `ss->x`, but it doesn't make sense type-wise to assign `&ss->x` (type `int **`) to `ss->next` (type `struct s *`).  You could also view `%rdi` as being a pointer to the struct `*ss` itself, and this is more sensible: `ss->next = ss;`.  It makes a circular linked list with a single node whose `next` is itself.

The moral here is that there can be different ways in C to refer to the same address, all of which will generate identical assembly, and you have to use common sense to make an educated guess as to which one the author more likely intended.  It's theoretically possible that the author of the C code wrote `ss->next = (struct s *)&(ss->x);` as the third line - we can't prove that they didn't - but `ss->next = ss;` is much more sensible and thus much more likely.

This sort of thing is why reverse engineering is an art as well as a science.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your reasoning. It makes a lot more sense now to think of it as a linked list. I also didn't realize the index of w.sh was out of bounds when I was writing up my question. Structs are just a little weird for me as someone with no experience with C and pointers until very recently.